# How do I dequeue using popLeft in a queue properly?

Tags: python, algorithm, stack, queue, logic

```
import collections
class MyStack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def push(self, value):
        self._data.append(value)

    def size(self):
        #Return the number of elements in the stack
        return len(self._data)

    def toString(self):
        #Return a string representing the content of this stack
        return str(self._data)

class MyQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = collections.deque([])

    def enqueue(self, value):
        self._data.append(value)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self._data.popleft()

    def size(self):
        #return the number of elements in the queue
        return len(self._data)

queue1 = MyQueue()
dq = MyStack()
stack1 = MyStack()

stack1.push(['stone', 'atone'])
print "size of stack is now :" ,stack1.size()
queue1.enqueue(stack1)
print "size of queue is now :", queue1.size()
print "size of stack is now :" ,stack1.size()
stack1.push(['stone', 'shone'])
stack1.push(['stone', 'scone'])

dq = queue1.dequeue() # i would like dq to be ['stone','atone']

print dq.toString()
```

This is a school assignment, I'm not allowed to modify codes for the functions enqueue and dequeue and def__init__(self).
I'm trying to use popleft as a means to dequeue an item from a queue. However, the compiler returns the whole queue rather than only the first stack of the queue while I'm using popleft. That being said , the size of the queue decreases by one. Any explanation for this?

The compiler returns [['stone', 'atone'], ['stone', 'shone'], ['stone', 'scone']] when I only want it to return ['stone', 'atone'].

Comment: You added the *Stack object* to the Queue, not the elements *in* the stack. That is why when you `.dequeue()` you get back the Stack object, which now contains `[['stone', 'atone'], ['stone', 'shone'], ['stone', 'scone']]` (which you `.push`ed on to the stack). I'm not sure I understand you question exactly, but that explains the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: In other words, I think you need to elaborate a bit more here. I suspect you are misunderstanding the first part of your assignment, are you being tasked to use a Stack to populate a Queue?

Comment: I am actually supposed to create a word ladder game following a list of data structures and algorithm implementation. I merely extracted some codes from my assignment to ask this question, otherwise the question would include way too many codes.

Anyway, I am merely following the algorithm given to me. For now, I need to dequeue the first item (which is a stack) from the queue and be able to print this first item (which is a stack) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the above comment, you are passing a `Stack` object not the elements in the stack. Try this one

```
import collections
class MyStack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def push(self, value):
        self._data.append(value)

    def size(self):
        #Return the number of elements in the stack
        return len(self._data)

    def toString(self):
        #Return a string representing the content of this stack
        return str(self._data)

class MyQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = collections.deque([])

    def enqueue(self, value):
        self._data.append(value)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self._data.popleft()

    def size(self):
        #return the number of elements in the queue
        return len(self._data)

queue1 = MyQueue()
dq = MyStack()
stack1 = MyStack()

stack1.push(['stone', 'atone'])
print "size of stack is now :" ,stack1.size()
queue1.enqueue(stack1.toString())
print "size of queue is now :", queue1.size()
print "size of stack is now :" ,stack1.size()
stack1.push(['stone', 'shone'])
stack1.push(['stone', 'scone'])

dq = queue1.dequeue() # i would like dq to be ['stone','atone']

print dq
```